# Posterior distribution for mean of a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Given $\bar x = 150$, $X \sim (\mu , 20^2)$ distributed normally with unknown mean and $\mu \sim (180, 40^2) $ distributed normally, find the posterior distribution for $\mu$ in terms of $n$.

I already have $f(\mu) = \frac{1}{40\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-1}{2} (\frac{\mu - 80}{40})^2}$ for the prior and have calculated $f(x \vert \mu) = (\frac{1}{20 \sqrt{2\pi}})^n \exp{\frac{-1}{2*20^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\mu )^2}$ for the likelihood

Then I understand that I have to use Bayes' Theorem, but I do not know where to go with the likelihood function to get to this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you multiply the prior density by the likelihood, you have something proportional to the posterior density.  You then need to adjust this (multiply or divide by a suitable constant) so that it integrates to $1$.  You may at some stage want to complete the square inside the exponential term